# Styling HTML to mimic Facebook like dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, styling

I need some advice and some help. I am not so much of a css guy, but I want to learn.

I am trying adjust some css for my drop down menu.

I have the following issues:

- The dropdown button should be as big as the image, leaving only the area of the dropdown triangle.
- The dropdown triangle should be aligned vertically in the middle and centered horizontally.
- The dropdown options should be aligned with the right border and open inwards towards the left, instead of the opposite.

Can someone help me with adjusting this?
I want to learn the techniques, but trial on error is such a long way.

My code is as folowing:

```
<html>
<head>
<head>
<body>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: white;
            font: normal 11px Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,Sans-Serif;
            color: #222;
            height: 380px;
        }

        .dropdown {
            display: block;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0px 3px;
            position: relative;
        }

        /* ===[ For demonstration ]=== */

        .dropdown { margin-top: 25px }

        /* ===[ End demonstration ]=== */

        .dropdown .dropdown_button {
            cursor: pointer;
            width: auto;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0px 0px;
            border: 1px solid silver;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 0px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #717780;
            line-height: 16px;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            background: white;
        }

        .dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked +  .dropdown_button {
            border: 1px solid #3B5998;
            color: white;
            background: silver;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
            border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
            border-bottom-color: silver;
        }

        .dropdown input[type="checkbox"] + .dropdown_button .arrow {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 1px;
            height: 1px;
            border-top: 5px solid silver;
            border-right: 5px solid transparent;
            border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        }

        .dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .dropdown_button .arrow { border-color: white transparent transparent transparent }

        .dropdown .dropdown_content {
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid #777;
            padding: 0px;
            background: white;
            margin: 0;
            display: none;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown_content li {
            list-style: none;
            margin-left: 0px;
            line-height: 16px;
            border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
            margin-top: 2px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown_content li:hover {
            background: silver;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown_content li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 2px 7px;
            padding-right: 15px;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown_content li:hover a {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }
        .dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .dropdown_content { display: block }
        .dropdown input[type="checkbox"] { display: none }
    </style>    

    Here there will be a lot of text and a lot of other menu buttons. So hope the angle of the dropdown will open to the left instead of the right.
    <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop1" />
        <label for="drop1" class="dropdown_button"><img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/43_43/images/live/p0/17/tx/p017txf6.jpg" height="43" width="43" /><span class="arrow"></span></label>
        <ul class="dropdown_content">
            <li><a href="#">Privacy settings</a></li>                       
            <li><a href="#">Account settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>                                
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I managed to fix the border around the image by correcting the `padding padding: 0px 0px;` but then I feel like working in blind...can someone help pointing me where to fix my adjustments?

Comment: "I want to learn the techniques, but trial on error is such a long way."  That's funny.  I recommend just going to facebook and right click on the menu and click "Inspect element."  You will be able to see what classes are being used.  It should be as simple as copy and paste.

Comment: Funny? I wrote that css is not my strongest side, and believe me I tried that and messed everything up.

Comment: I have done what you are trying to do and I know it's as simple as copying and pasting code.  What are you having trouble with specifically and we can try to help?

Comment: I have tried using firebug, but messed most of it up. I boiled it down to this, and need some advice or pointers to correct the rest. OMG!

Comment: I believe I have written the three bullets of what I am missing now...you want me to be more specific?

Comment: It's kind of hard to visualize what you want based on your descriptions.  You would probably have better luck if you post a screenshot of what you want; and a jsfiddle.net of what you have and someone will be able to send you the missing link between the two.

Comment: Have you tried copying my code and save it locally? Then you will see some minor cosmetic corrections I want. The triangluar symbol is not aligned correctly, I want it centered and vertically in middle.
And then I need the menu to open inwards, meaning that the right border of the button should be aligned with the dropdown border.

Comment: Here I have created a jsfiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/FSn4T/.  Just post a screenshot of what you want.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zsp7t/1/

Comment: I tried to work around your code in fiddle. It's too much of a mess for me to continue. But I did have some luck with adding everything in a div with a width of 100px and floating everything inside to the right to give it the right alignment. Was also able to position the drop-down arrow in the place you asked about. I used the position and top properties to accomplish this move.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/f/59/jo6t.png

Comment: I have attached an image of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Joe_G It is actually working quiet well. I took the css style and added to my html, and now only the triangle symbol needs to be v-aligned middle, and is it possible for the dropdown to collapse when you click outside the dropdown field?

Comment: Does it need to be moved up or down? You can change the 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' values inside the #arrowSpan class to change the vertical positioning of it (in the fiddle or using developer tools).

Comment: It needs to be moved up. I tried messing around with the margins in arrowSpan, but the triangle symbol is fixed, so it is not working. Also I am wondering whether it is possible to collapse the dropdown menu when you click outside.

Comment: I got it fixed. Now how do I accept an answer when all we have here are comments? :)

Comment: Still - is it possible to collapse the dropdown, when clicking outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your span an id of 'arrowSpan' and apply this style in your css:

```
#arrowSpan{
    display:block;
    margin-left:17px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Also add `position:absolute;` and `right:0` to your `.dropdown .dropdown_content` styles.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zsp7t/1/

As for collapsing the dropdown when clicking outside, it is possible. There's a bunch of examples online using jQuery, here's a couple that can help you get started:

- [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)
- [Hiding a div by selecting anywhere outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815554/hiding-a-div-by-selecting-anywhere-outside-of-it)

You also mentioned that you wanted to learn more, so check these sites out to help you increase your skills:

- http://www.codecademy.com/
- http://www.codeschool.com/courses

Comment: Thanks...I will go through your links.